# Trying to understand a Booth's multiplication radix-4 implementation

Tags: vhdl, multiplication

I'm trying to understand some VHDL code describing Booth multiplication with a radix-4 implementation. I know how the algorithm works but I can't seem to understand what some parts of the code do specifically.
Here is the whole implementation:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

entity booth_mult is
  port(
    clk             : in std_logic;
    start           : in std_logic;
    n_reset : in std_logic;
    mcand       : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    mplier      : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    done        : out std_logic;
      product   : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
end booth_mult;

architecture arch of booth_mult is
    type state_type is(IDLE, BUSY);
    attribute ENUM_ENCODING : string;                                           -- used for explicit state machine encoding
    attribute ENUM_ENCODING of state_type   : type is "01 10";
    signal state_reg, state_next                                : state_type;

    signal q_reg, q_next                                                : unsigned(6 downto 0);
    signal mcand_reg                                                    : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);                -- registers for the multiplicand
    signal prod_reg, prod_next                              : std_logic_vector(32 downto 0);
    signal result_reg, result_next                          : std_logic_vector(32 downto 0);            -- this holds the result before shift
    signal q_add, q_reset                                           : std_logic;

begin
    -- increment sequential logic on rising clock edge process
    process(clk, n_reset)   
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if n_reset = '0' then
                state_reg <= IDLE;
                q_reg <= (others => '0');
                prod_reg <= (others => '0');
            else
                q_reg <= q_next;
                state_reg <= state_next;
                prod_reg <= prod_next(32) & prod_next(32 downto 1);  -- shift prod register each time
                result_reg <= prod_next;
            end if; 
        end if;
    end process;

  -- control unit process
    process(state_reg, q_reg, result_reg, start, prod_reg, mplier, mcand )                  
        begin
            -- initialize signals and no register update
            q_add <= '0';
            q_reset <= '0';
            done <= '0';
            state_next <= state_reg;
            prod_next <= prod_reg;
            result_next <= result_reg;  

            case state_reg is

                when IDLE => 
                    if (start = '1') then   -- load numbers to multiply
                        mcand_reg <= mcand;
                        prod_next(32 downto 17) <= (others => '0');  -- prod_next reg = [0000...0000(mplier)0]
                        prod_next(16 downto 1) <= mplier;
                        prod_next(0) <= '0';
                        state_next <= BUSY;
                    end if;

                when BUSY =>
                    q_add <= '1';
                    if (q_reg = '0' & conv_unsigned(16, 7)(6 downto 1)  and start /= '1') then  -- after 8 clock cycles multiplication is done
                        product <= prod_next(32) & prod_next(32  downto 2);
                        done <= '1' ;
                        q_add <= '0';
                        q_reset <= '1';
                        state_next <= IDLE;
                    end if;
                    -- radix-4 decoding
                    case result_reg(2 downto 0) is     
                        when "001" | "010" =>   -- + mcand
                            prod_next <= ((prod_reg(32) & prod_reg(32 downto 17)) + (mcand_reg(16 - 1) & mcand_reg)) & prod_reg(16 downto 1);
                        when "011" =>                       -- + 2*mcand
                            prod_next <= ((prod_reg(32) & prod_reg(32 downto 17)) + (mcand_reg & '0' )) & prod_reg(16 downto 1);
                        when "100" =>                       -- - 2*mcand
                            prod_next <= ((prod_reg(32) & prod_reg(32 downto 17)) - (mcand_reg & '0' )) & prod_reg(16 downto 1);
                        when "101" | "110" =>   -- - mcand
                            prod_next <= ((prod_reg(32) & prod_reg(32 downto 17)) - (mcand_reg(16 - 1) & mcand_reg)) & prod_reg(16 downto 1); -- 2*mcand
                        when others =>                  -- shift only
                            prod_next <= prod_reg(32) & prod_reg(32 downto 1);
                    end case;

                end case;

    end process;


    -- timer/counter for timed logic
  q_next <= (others => '0') when q_reset = '1' else         -- reset q_next to bottom if q_reset is 1
                   q_reg + 1 when q_add = '1' else                            -- increment q_reg by 1 if q_add is 1
                   q_reg;   


end arch;
```

What I don't understand is:

1. `if (q_reg = '0' & conv_unsigned(16, 7)(6 downto 1)  and start /= '1') then  -- after 8 clock cycles multiplication is done`.
   The comment makes it obvious but what does it do exactly? The documentation for `conv_unsigned` says that it should return the value 16 as an unsigned value (which it is) of size 7 (which I guess it could be). Doesn't &ing whatever is returned by `conv_usigned` with `0` just make the whole thing 0?
2. `prod_next <= prod_reg(32) & prod_reg(32 downto 1);`
   Referring to the comment again, this should just be a shift. What I understand is actually happening is that the 32nd bit of the `prod_reg` register is &ed with each bit of the same register between the 32nd and 1st bits and then assigned to `prod_next`. How exactly is this a shift?

The code works when tested so this is 100% a problem with my lack of VHDL knowledge so please forgive me if the questions are dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer Q1: '&' is the concatenation operator, so `'0' & seven_bit_number` makes an 8 bit number.

So this whole expression `'0' & conv_unsigned(16, 7)(6 downto 1)` is a longwinded way of saying `B"001000"`, or 8. I think...

Did this come from an Obfuscated VHDL contest? 
Such laborious fighting with the type system usually means there's something you're missing, or something badly wrong with the design.

I'd delete these non-standard libraries:

```
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;
```

in favour of the standard, 
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
and simply write

```
if q_reg = 8 and start /= '1' then
```

Note that the incomprehensible comment now not only makes sense, but it's redundant.

(There will probably be other non-standard library dependences to clean up too, so whether this is really worth doing is up to you).

And a minor note on Q2: the operation isn't a shift : it appears to be a shift with sign extension, so there may be signed numbers in there. Again, making `prod_next` a `numeric_std.signed` if that's appropriate will make it clear what's really going on, paying off a little bit of technical debt.

Comment: Looking at it now I can see how it might have come from converting a variable-sized multiplication unit to a 16-bit one by just replacing the variable with a hard-coded value. Thank you!